# How to make the url of links on Screens in Moqui to be relative rather than absolute?

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, freemarker, moqui

The link for JavaScript and CSS files appear to have an absolute URL like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.dp.com:8080/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"  language="javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.dp.com:8080/js/bootstrap.min.js" language="javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://test.dp.com:8080/js/holder.js" language="javascript">
    <link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but I would like them to be:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" language="javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js" language="javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="holder.js" language="javascript">
    <link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It is also similar to the link on Screen.

I would like to have them relative, then it can be possible to add a reverse proxy in front of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These come from the Header.html.ftl file in the webroot component and use values like this:

```
${sri.buildUrl(scriptLocation).url}
```

There are many URLs generated like this with the full URL including hostname and such. When not running locally you'll almost always need to set the external hostname and ports in the Moqui Conf XML file. For example:

```
<webapp-list>
    <webapp name="webroot" http-host="www.mydomain.com" http-port="80" https-enabled="false">
        <root-screen host=".*" location="component://webroot/screen/webroot.xml"/>
    </webapp>
</webapp-list>
```

Note that this still has https-enabled="false". If you set that to true also set the @https-host and @https-post attributes.

Note that if you leave any of http-host, http-port, https-host, or https-port empty they will default to the hostname and port on the HTTP request. This is the way to handle it for virtual hosting for multi-tenant or multi-root screen setups. For this to work it is necessary that any load balancer or other other proxy (such as mod-proxy on httpd) be setup to pass through this HTTP request information.

Comment: Hi David, 

the link appears to look like http://localhost:8080/apps/hm/Task/TaskSummary?workEffortId=HM-004. 

Although it could be changed in the webapp configuration. But I want to make multiple hosts work on same moqui instance. 

For example: let a.test.com and b.test.com point to the application (via nginx), and each access to different tenant (tell by the hostname). Then the link in the page should be prefixed by respective hostname. Using relative path will simply make it work.

Comment: It may work to add multi <webapp> in conf file (I haven't test it), but it seems that it requires a restart of moqui application to reload the conf file. However, I would like to have it to be change on the fly and dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jimmy. I updated the answer to address this concern.